# How does Google SignIn in JavaScript work with subdomains in Safari when "Allow from websites i visit" option is checked?

Tags: javascript, safari, google-signin, oauth-2.0, cookie-policy

I am trying to achieve Google SignIn using it's JavaScript API on a web app that i am currently working on.

The scenario is very simple:

When user navigates to `example.com`, a *SignIn with Google* button is presented, which `onClick` authenticates the user; among others, it initializes the Google API with `cookie_policy` like this:

```
`
auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    cookie_policy: 'https://example.com'
});
`
```

After successfully signin the user in, it redirects (from JS) to the account page which is served at `https://account.example.com`.

On *Chrome* or *Firefox* (for example), the login works smoothly - no issues.

However, on *Safari* on *MacOS* and **any browser** on *iOS*, the user gets into an (almost) endless loop: because the signin check fails on the account page, user is redirected back to the landing page where the signin succeeds and then the loop starts again ...

This behavior is not happening - i.e. everything works fine again - if the user goes to `Safari > Preferences > Privacy` and in the *Cookies and website data* option list checks the 4th option, ***Always allow*** instead of the default ***Allow from websites I visit***.

**Does anyone know how could this be worked around?**

Thanks in advance,

Ogg